# How to declare variables to be used in $(document).ready(); and PreSaveAction

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to make a check-in/check-out system for a sharepoint list and I need some functionality using the same variables bout in the $(document).ready and the PresaveAction. So far everything I've tried results in the presave action not knowing the values of the variables. Is this it possible to use the same variables in both those functions?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variables at the page scope, outside your $(document).ready, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myGlobalVar = "123456";

    $(document).ready(function () {          
        myGlobalVar = "Changed to abcdefg";
        var myLocalVar = "zzzzzz";
    });

    function PreSaveAction() 
    {  
          alert(myGlobalVar);       // Outputs "Changed to abcdefg"
          alert(myLocalVar);        // Outputs "undefined"; 
    }   
</script>
```